# Custom jQuery script not working on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have enqueued a script in my WordPress theme's functions.php.  I can see in dev tools that WordPress is loading the script.  The script does not seem to function though.  It won't even do console.log.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('h1').html('jQuery is working');
});



jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    console.log('jQuery is working');
});
```

The above scripts do nothing.  I tried it just using the normal $ instead of jQuery as well, with no success (Before I knew WordPress uses noConflict).

Any idea why the script refuses to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what the precise issue was behind the problem, but I found that the script loading function I had used in my functions.php file was also overriding WordPress and loading an older version of jQuery.  Removing that so that WordPress loaded it's default jQuery fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can try below code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('jQuery is working');
});
```

No need to use $ as a argument in function.